# The class 'Symfony\Component\Form\Form' was not found in the chain configured namespaces during Form Submission

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I'm building an interface that will allow people in the office to edit details of specific records. Currently I have a form like this:

**view.html.twig**

```
<!-- Modal Windows: Edit Instructor Personal Details -->
<div id="editPersonal" style="display:none;">
    <div class="modal-head">
        <h2>Edit Personal Details For: <font-color="red !important">{{instructor.firstName}} {{instructor.surname}}</font></h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <form action="#" method="post" {{ form_enctype(ipde) }} id="editPersonalDetails" class="modaledit">
        <table class="modalform-col1">
            <tbody>
                <tr class="hidden">
                    <th>{{ form_label(ipde.id, 'ID*', { 'attr': {'class': 'title'} }) }}</th>
                    <td>
                        {{ form_errors(ipde.id) }}
                        {{ form_widget(ipde.id, { 'attr': {'class': 'textfield'}}) }}
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>{{ form_label(ipde.firstName, 'First Name*', { 'attr': {'class': 'title'} }) }}</th>
                    <td>
                        {{ form_errors(ipde.firstName) }}
                        {{ form_widget(ipde.firstName, { 'attr': {'class': 'text'}}) }}
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>{{ form_label(ipde.surname, 'Surname*', { 'attr': {'class': 'title'} }) }}</th>
                    <td>
                        {{ form_errors(ipde.surname) }}
                        {{ form_widget(ipde.surname, { 'attr': {'class': 'text'}}) }}
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>{{ form_label(ipde.address1, 'Address Line 1*', { 'attr': {'class': 'title'} }) }}</th>
                    <td>
                        {{ form_errors(ipde.address1) }}
                        {{ form_widget(ipde.address1, { 'attr': {'class': 'text'}}) }}
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>{{ form_label(ipde.address2, 'Address Line 2', { 'attr': {'class': 'title'} }) }}</th>
                    <td>
                        {{ form_errors(ipde.address2) }}
                        {{ form_widget(ipde.address2, { 'attr': {'class': 'text'}}) }}
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>{{ form_label(ipde.town, 'Town*', { 'attr': {'class': 'title'} }) }}</th>
                    <td>
                        {{ form_errors(ipde.town) }}
                        {{ form_widget(ipde.town, { 'attr': {'class': 'text'}}) }}
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>{{ form_label(ipde.county, 'County*', { 'attr': {'class': 'title'} }) }}</th>
                    <td>
                        {{ form_errors(ipde.county) }}
                        {{ form_widget(ipde.county, { 'attr': {'class': 'text'}}) }}
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>{{ form_label(ipde.postcode, 'Postcode*', { 'attr': {'class': 'title'} }) }}</th>
                    <td>
                        {{ form_errors(ipde.postcode) }}
                        {{ form_widget(ipde.postcode, { 'attr': {'class': 'text'}}) }}
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>{{ form_label(ipde.email, 'Email*', { 'attr': {'class': 'title'} }) }}</th>
                    <td>
                        {{ form_errors(ipde.email) }}
                        {{ form_widget(ipde.email, { 'attr': {'class': 'text'}}) }}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <div class="modal-placeright">
            <a href="#close" rel="modal:close" class="closebutton">Close Without Saving</a>
            <input type="submit" value="Save Changes" id="savebuttonpr" class="savebutton" />
            {{ form_rest(ipde) }} 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my Controller looks like this:

**DefaultController.php**

```
<?php

namespace PCUK\InstructorBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use PCUK\InstructorBundle\Form\IpdeType;
use PCUK\InstructorBundle\Form\IrType;
use PCUK\InstructorBundle\Form\BaType;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{

    public function viewAction($instructor, Request $request)
    {
        // Database connection
        $insrep = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        // Get Instructor from Entity for Form use
        $instructorQ = $insrep->getRepository('InstructorBundle:MapInstructors')->find($instructor);

        // Get Shared Branches from Entity for Form use
        $instructorS = $insrep->getRepository('InstructorBundle:MapInstructorShared')->find($instructor);

        // Generate Form to edit Instructor Personal Details
        $ipde = $this->createForm( new IpdeType(), $instructorQ);

        // Handle Form submission to edit Instructor Personal Details
        if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
            $ipde->bind($request);

            if ($ipde->isValid()) {
                // perform some action, such as saving the task to the database

                //if ($this->request->isXmlHttpRequest()){
                       //return data ajax requires.
                //}
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $em->persist($ipde);
                $em->flush();


                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('task_success'));
            }
        }

        // Generate Form to edit Instructor Records
        $ir = $this->createForm( new IrType(), $instructorQ);

        // Generate Form to edit Instructor Records
        $ba = $this->createForm( new BaType(), $instructorS);

        // Return data to view
        return $this->render('InstructorBundle:Default:view.html.twig', array(
            'ipde' => $ipde->createView(),
            'ir' => $ir->createView(),
            'ba' => $ba->createView()
        ));
    }
}
```

However, when I go to submit the form I get the following error:

> "The class 'Symfony\Component\Form\Form' was not found in the chain
>   configured namespaces PCUK\InstructorBundle\Entity"

I have built a Symfony2 project before and I've referenced it against this current project to see if I've included the `Symfony\Component\Form\Form`, if that's actually what the problem is.

What's happening?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are persisting `$ipde` which happens to be a form, not an entity !

That's probably the source of error.

Comment: So, how would I persist the form to the database then? I thought that's what I was doing in the first place...

Comment: it's the entity that should be persisted in the database not the form,in your case that would be `$instructorQ` I guess

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a "use" statement in all of your *Type() classes?
i guess it should be like

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
```

AbstractType have a use of Form namespace.

Comment: I've checked and I have included that name space in the *Type class. No joy though!