# How to persist a form to a database, NOT entity, in Symfony2

Tags: php, database, forms, symfony

I'm currently rebuilding a web app using Symfony2. I want users to update specific records that they have on our MySQL database. However, the users aren't confident computer users and don't like the way the web application (in its current form) works. 
Therefore, from a UI/UX perspective, I decided to use 2 forms to edit specific data instead of the current 1 form that the users don't like.

The MySQL database table in question holds numerous fields of information, such as their personal details and other information relevant to them. The forms are split up to reflect this, with the idea that one form updates the personal details, and one form updates the rest, so the user doesn't have to deal with one long form.

At the moment though, when I go to use one form, I get the error:

> The class 'Symfony\Component\Form\Form' was not found in the chain
>   configured namespaces during Form Submission

This error was solved in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16173451/the-class-symfony-component-form-form-was-not-found-in-the-chain-configured-na). However, it's left me with a problem. Currently, because I've split the form in two, I'm unable to save this data to the database. I can overcome this by using just one form, but then this goes against the wishes of the users of the database. Furthermore, I know it's entirely possible to use two or more forms to add specific data to a single database as I've done it before, just not in Symfony.

Does anyone know, or have a suggestion, as to how I can overcome this? Changing the database is out of the question, due to the sheer volume of current data that is on there.

**UPDATE**

Here are the missing view, controller and form files.

**view.html.twig**

```
<!-- Modal Windows: Edit Instructor Personal Details -->
<div id="editPersonal" style="display:none;">
    <div class="modal-head">
        <h2>Edit Personal Details For: <font-color="red !important">{{instructor.firstName}} {{instructor.surname}}</font></h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <form action="#" method="post" {{ form_enctype(ipde) }} id="editPersonalDetails" class="modaledit">
        <table class="modalform-col1">
            <tbody>
                <tr class="hidden">
                    <th>{{ form_label(ipde.id, 'ID*', { 'attr': {'class': 'title'} }) }}</th>
                    <td>
                        {{ form_errors(ipde.id) }}
                        {{ form_widget(ipde.id, { 'attr': {'class': 'textfield'}}) }}
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>{{ form_label(ipde.firstName, 'First Name*', { 'attr': {'class': 'title'} }) }}</th>
                    <td>
                        {{ form_errors(ipde.firstName) }}
                        {{ form_widget(ipde.firstName, { 'attr': {'class': 'text'}}) }}
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>{{ form_label(ipde.surname, 'Surname*', { 'attr': {'class': 'title'} }) }}</th>
                    <td>
                        {{ form_errors(ipde.surname) }}
                        {{ form_widget(ipde.surname, { 'attr': {'class': 'text'}}) }}
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>{{ form_label(ipde.address1, 'Address Line 1*', { 'attr': {'class': 'title'} }) }}</th>
                    <td>
                        {{ form_errors(ipde.address1) }}
                        {{ form_widget(ipde.address1, { 'attr': {'class': 'text'}}) }}
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>{{ form_label(ipde.address2, 'Address Line 2', { 'attr': {'class': 'title'} }) }}</th>
                    <td>
                        {{ form_errors(ipde.address2) }}
                        {{ form_widget(ipde.address2, { 'attr': {'class': 'text'}}) }}
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>{{ form_label(ipde.town, 'Town*', { 'attr': {'class': 'title'} }) }}</th>
                    <td>
                        {{ form_errors(ipde.town) }}
                        {{ form_widget(ipde.town, { 'attr': {'class': 'text'}}) }}
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>{{ form_label(ipde.county, 'County*', { 'attr': {'class': 'title'} }) }}</th>
                    <td>
                        {{ form_errors(ipde.county) }}
                        {{ form_widget(ipde.county, { 'attr': {'class': 'text'}}) }}
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>{{ form_label(ipde.postcode, 'Postcode*', { 'attr': {'class': 'title'} }) }}</th>
                    <td>
                        {{ form_errors(ipde.postcode) }}
                        {{ form_widget(ipde.postcode, { 'attr': {'class': 'text'}}) }}
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>{{ form_label(ipde.email, 'Email*', { 'attr': {'class': 'title'} }) }}</th>
                    <td>
                        {{ form_errors(ipde.email) }}
                        {{ form_widget(ipde.email, { 'attr': {'class': 'text'}}) }}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <div class="modal-placeright">
            <a href="#close" rel="modal:close" class="closebutton">Close Without Saving</a>
            <input type="submit" value="Save Changes" id="savebuttonpr" class="savebutton" />
            {{ form_rest(ipde) }} 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**DefaultController.php**

```
<?php

namespace PCUK\InstructorBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use PCUK\InstructorBundle\Form\IpdeType;
use PCUK\InstructorBundle\Form\IrType;
use PCUK\InstructorBundle\Form\BaType;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{

    public function viewAction($instructor, Request $request)
    {
        // Database connection
        $insrep = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        // Get Instructor from Entity for Form use
        $instructorQ = $insrep->getRepository('InstructorBundle:MapInstructors')->find($instructor);

        // Get Shared Branches from Entity for Form use
        $instructorS = $insrep->getRepository('InstructorBundle:MapInstructorShared')->find($instructor);

        // Generate Form to edit Instructor Personal Details
        $ipde = $this->createForm( new IpdeType(), $instructorQ);

        // Handle Form submission to edit Instructor Personal Details
        if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
            $ipde->bind($request);

            if ($ipde->isValid()) {
                // perform some action, such as saving the task to the database

                //if ($this->request->isXmlHttpRequest()){
                       //return data ajax requires.
                //}
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $em->persist($ipde);
                $em->flush();


                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('task_success'));
            }
        }

        // Generate Form to edit Instructor Records
        $ir = $this->createForm( new IrType(), $instructorQ);

        // Generate Form to edit Instructor Records
        $ba = $this->createForm( new BaType(), $instructorS);

        // Return data to view
        return $this->render('InstructorBundle:Default:view.html.twig', array(
            'ipde' => $ipde->createView(),
            'ir' => $ir->createView(),
            'ba' => $ba->createView()
        ));
    }
}
```

**IpdeType.php - Personal Details Form**

```
<?php
// src/PCUK/InstructorBundle/Form/Type/IpdeType.php
// This is to handle forms for the Instructor Personal Details Form
namespace PCUK\InstructorBundle\Form;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Form;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FileField;

class IpdeType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('id', 'integer', array('required'=>false));
        //Personal Details
        $builder->add('firstName', 'text', array('required'=>false));
        $builder->add('surname', 'text', array('required'=>false));
        $builder->add('address1', 'text', array('required'=>false));
        $builder->add('address2', 'text', array('required'=>false));
        $builder->add('town', 'text', array('required'=>false));
        $builder->add('county', 'text', array('required'=>false));
        $builder->add('postcode', 'text', array('required'=>false));
        $builder->add('email', 'text', array('required'=>false));
        $builder->add('phone', 'text', array('required'=>false));
        $builder->add('mobile', 'text', array('required'=>false));
        $builder->add('notes', 'text', array('required'=>false));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'ipde';
    }
}
```

**IrType.php - Other Information Form**

```
<?php
// src/PCUK/InstructorBundle/Form/Type/IrType.php
// This is to handle forms for the Instructor Records Form
namespace PCUK\InstructorBundle\Form;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Form;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FileField;

class IrType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('id', 'integer', array('required'=>false));
        $builder->add('primaryArea', 'integer', array('required'=>false));
        $builder->add('primaryBranch','entity', array('class'=>'PCUK\InstructorBundle\Entity\MapBranches', 'property'=>'branchname' ));
        $builder->add('begin', 'date', array('required'=>false));
        $builder->add('lastCrb', 'date', array('required'=>false));
        $builder->add('latestCpd', 'date', array('required'=>false));
        $builder->add('preferredLevel','entity', array('class'=>'PCUK\InstructorBundle\Entity\MapInstructorLevels', 'property'=>'name' ));
        $builder->add('preferredDiscipline','entity', array('class'=>'PCUK\InstructorBundle\Entity\MapInstructorLevels', 'property'=>'name' ));
        $builder->add('currentLevel','entity', array('class'=>'PCUK\InstructorBundle\Entity\MapInstructorLevels', 'property'=>'name' ));
        $builder->add('bhs', 'checkbox', array('required'=>false));
        $builder->add('visiting','entity', array('class'=>'PCUK\InstructorBundle\Entity\MapInstructorVis', 'property'=>'name' ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'ir';
    }
}
```

**Update: 29/04/13**
Following james_t's advice, I split the Entity in to two, one for each of the forms respectively. However, the original error still occurs.

I've also created a new action in the controller, and because the split entity hasn't fixed the issue, I reverted back to using a single entity. My controller now looks as follows:

**viewAction**
public function viewAction($instructor, Request $request)
{
    // Database connection
    $insrep = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

```
// Get IPDE from Entity for Form use
$instructorIpde = $insrep->getRepository('InstructorBundle:MapInstructors')->find($instructor);

// Generate Form to edit Instructor Personal Details
$ipde = $this->createForm( new IpdeType(), $instructorIpde);

// Get IR from Entity for Form use
$instructorIr = $insrep->getRepository('InstructorBundle:MapInstructors')->find($instructor);

// Generate Form to edit Instructor Records
$ir = $this->createForm( new IrType(), $instructorIr);

// Get Shared Branches from Entity for Form use
$instructorBa = $insrep->getRepository('InstructorBundle:MapInstructorShared')->find($instructor);

// Generate Form to edit Instructor Records
$ba = $this->createForm( new BaType(), $instructorBa);

// Return data to view
return $this->render('InstructorBundle:Default:view.html.twig', array(
    'pagename' => $iname . ' - Instructors', 
    'ipde' => $ipde->createView(),
    'ir' => $ir->createView(),
    'ba' => $ba->createView(),
        'iid' => $instructor
));
```

}

**ipdeAction**

public function ipdeAction($instructor, Request $request)
{
    // Database connection
    $insrep = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

```
// Get IPDE from Entity for Form use
$instructorIpde = $insrep->getRepository('InstructorBundle:MapInstructors')->find($instructor);

// Generate Form to edit Instructor Personal Details
$ipde = $this->createForm( new IpdeType(), $instructorIpde);

// Handle Form submission to edit Instructor Personal Details
if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
    $ipde->bind($request);

    if ($ipde->isValid()) {
        // perform some action, such as saving the task to the database

        //if ($this->request->isXmlHttpRequest()){
               //return data ajax requires.
        //}
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($ipde);
        $em->flush();

        $params = array(
            'instructor'  => $instructor,
        );

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('instructor_viewinstructor', $params));
    }
}
```

}

I've also fixed updated my **view.html.twig** file from this:

```
<form action="#" method="post" {{ form_enctype(ipde) }} id="editPersonalDetails" class="modaledit">
```

to this:

```
<form action="{{ path('instructor_viewinstructor_ipde', {'instructor' :iid}) }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(ipde) }} id="editPersonalDetails" class="modaledit">
```

My routing.yml file also looks like this now:

```
instructor_viewinstructor:
    pattern:  /instructors/view/{instructor}
    defaults: { _controller: InstructorBundle:Default:view }

instructor_viewinstructor_ipde:
    pattern:  /instructors/view/{instructor}/ipde
    defaults: { _controller: InstructorBundle:Default:ipde }
    requirements:
        _method:  POST
```

Comment: Code of the forms and the controller would be helpful. Are the forms seperate to edit, or one after one (like a setup wizard)?

Comment: Sorry, knew there was something I had forgot! I've added them on there now for you to see.

Comment: When you say database, you mean table right? There's nothing wrong with using Native Queries with Doctrine and reading request variables, It's more code but that will work. Also, forms don't require entities. It sounds like you have a display problem, just use [embedded forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#embedding-a-single-object) and then use your template to make it 'easy' for your users.

Comment: I've split the Entity in to two, with both entities containing only fields for the respective forms. However, I'm still getting that error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much searching, I came across this entry in the Symfony2 [Cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/registration_form.html).

To be honest, I skipped the whole part of building the forms etc because I feel that I haven't done it wrong (that is up for debate I know). I felt that the issue was concerned with saving this data to the database, so I skipped down to this section of the [cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/registration_form.html#handling-the-form-submission), which spoke about the code saving the data to the database.

My code has been this:

```
// Database connection
$insrep = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

if ($ipde->isValid()) {
    // perform some action, such as saving the task to the database

    //if ($this->request->isXmlHttpRequest()){
           //return data ajax requires.
    //}
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($ipde);
    $em->flush();

    $params = array(
        'instructor'  => $instructor,
    );

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('instructor_viewinstructor', $params));
}
```

In the documentation, its this:

```
if ($form->isValid()) {
    $registration = $form->getData();

    $em->persist($registration->getUser());
    $em->flush();

    return $this->redirect(...);
}

return $this->render(
    'AcmeAccountBundle:Account:register.html.twig',
    array('form' => $form->createView())
);
```

The difference I found was that I've been using `$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();`, while the documentation suggests you use `$registration = $form->getData();`. I changed my code to use the `->getData()` code, and it works. No more errors, and the data is saved to the database!!!!

Answer (score 1):

It seems a bit odd to me the fact that you are generating 3 forms (1 of them twice with the same entity, **$ir** and **$ipde**). The error you are getting could be related to that.

I've done that before and I can share some guidelines for you:

- You don't need a separate entity for each form, you need a separate form for your entity. Don't take me wrong, It could work either way, but it doesn't really make a difference. In your code you are just using twice as much connections than required.
- You are passing 3 forms to your view but rendering just one, why?, unless you use AJAX, it doesn't make sense.

Let me describe the way to go:

1. **Create the entities** your application needs (generally one per table), you could split them but that's generally only necessary when working with more complex logic (i.e. different kind of permission / ownership over the same row by different users, though that is kind of [smelly](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/05/code-smells.html)).
2. If you want to use the validation component to make sure you are getting good data, use **[validation groups](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/validation.html#validation-groups)**, one group for each form you want to build).
3. **Create a form type** for each form you want to build. Sounds kind of obvious. You can have as many form types for any entity as you want. On each form, include only the fields that you are interested in.
4. **Create a view** for each one of your forms. Very straight forward.
5. Here is where the things change the most. What you actually need, is to have **one controller action per form**, don't mix them, you save nothing. Each controller action should:

   - Load the entity you are interested in
   - Build a form of the correct type.
   - If GET, then render **just one** form and return.
   - If POST, bind the request, save and do stuff.

Basically the workflow would be something like:

- The user wants to edit the entity id=X,
- You call the controller that handles the data you want to edit and return the form.
- The user submits the form and you save the data. You could play with **redirect** to chain both parts of the process, just redirect to the url of your second controller which handles the extended information. If you are chaining, you might find useful to use [flash messages](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/controller.html#flash-messages) to let the user know the information was saved.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have played with using a separate controller action to perform the save, but this damn error still appears. The problem I feel is that the form can't be submitted to the database. I am intending to use AJAX, but I want a fall back in case they dont have Javascript. So I'm trying to get it to work at it's most basic level before moving on to the AJAX calls. Also, having 3 forms is for UX purposes, so I don't overwhelm computer illiterate people with masses amounts of data.

Comment: I know what you mean from a UX perspective, but mixing things like that doesn't seem to be a good practice from a server application design point-of-view. There is something called [single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). You also need to keep separated the controllers when using AJAX and use template inheritance to merge all 3 forms on the same page. Keeping everything on it's own place can help you prevent these kind of errors.

Comment: I don't think I completely follow you regarding your separation of controllers. I know I should us separate controllers, and I have done now. But this error still occurs, when it shouldn't?

Comment: The separation of controllers is just a measure to prevent you to end with a bunch of spaghetti code. Please update your question with the new code, including the entities and all relevant modules to see if I can help to spot why does it show up.

Comment: I've updated the question with more code. The Entity file was generated directly using the console.

Comment: I've found the problem, please refer to my answer.